# some functions, ploting them and defining positive and negative areas

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry, functions, analytic-geometry

I have four following functions. I need to plot them and define positive and negative defined area. I have done most of them. But, i want you to check them, and correct them if false.

---

(1) $F(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$

for $x^2+2y^2=1$ , the graph is that

[image]

$C=\{(x,y)| -1\lt x \lt 1\  and -1/\sqrt{2} \lt y \lt 1/\sqrt {2}\} $

i.e the set C refers to inside of the ellipse

in this set C, the function is positive defined.

---

(2) $F(x,y)=xy$

for $xy=1$, the graph is that

[image]

this is hyperbol.

$C=\{(x,y)|  x \lt 0 \   and\  y\lt 0,\ x\gt 0 \  and \ y\gt 0 \} $

in this set C, the function is positive defined.

---

(3) $F(x,y)=x+2y^2$

for $x+2y^2=0$ the graph is that

[image]

well, I cannot the set C which shows the positive and negative defined areas of the function.

please help me doing this.

---

(4) $F(x,y)=x^2+3xy+3y^2$

I can neither graph this function nor define the set C (positive and negatife defined areas).

---

Especailly, I cannot do part (3) and (4).

Hopefully help me doing these two parts. And please check other two parts (1) and(2). Thank you so much.

Comment: your $C$ in (1) describes a rectangle, and,  not the bounded part of the ellipse. Further that $F$ is positive almost everywhere (i.e. $\Bbb R^2-(0,0)$) because is a sum of squares, being zero only at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Okay, now, I see. Well, how can I describe what you said as a set? Can you show this? @janmarqz thank you. And also, can you answer part(3) and (4)?

Comment: the bounded part of your ellipse (without the border) is  $C=\{(x,y)\mid -1< x< 1\ \& \ -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}\}$... the other items in a while

Comment: meanwhile, for (4) use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5Bx%5E2+%2B+3+x+y+%2B+3+y%5E2+%3D%3D+1%2C+%7Bx%2C+-2.5%2C+2.5%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-2.5%2C+2.5%7D%5D to get an idea. Later I'll abound.

Comment: i'm waiting for you. thank you :) @janmarqz

Comment: I will post in "another-while" a technique to decide for your $F$ in (4), but I would like to know from you this: *do you know how to manage changes-of-basis in $\Bbb R^2$?*

Comment: i know, but i cannot remember because long times pass after i learned. if you give a breif abouthe changes of basis in $\Bbb R^2$, i will remember and perfectly understand:) Also, there is a part(3) :) dear @janmarqz

Comment: well my friend, at https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/change-of-basis-and-change-of-components/ you could see an example of how to  find the new components of a vector when a change of basis happens... the answer that I'm gonna post uses those ideas

Comment: okay, well, will you show answers of part(3)&(4)? @janmarqz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(4)

The function $F(x,y)=x^2+3xy+3y^2$ can be thought as the quadratic form
$$F(x,y)=(x,y)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\2&3\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right).\qquad (*)$$

Let us abbreviate $p=\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)$ and
$Q=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\2&3\end{array}\right)$.

Now $Q$ isn't symmetric but can be decomposed as 
$$Q=\frac{1}{2}(Q+Q^{\top})+\frac{1}{2}(Q-Q^{\top}).$$ 
This decomposition gives us the matrices 
$$S=\frac{1}{2}(Q+Q^{\top})\quad \mbox{and}\quad A=\frac{1}{2}(Q-Q^{\top}),$$
which are $S$ symmetric and $A$ antisymmetric.
The matrix $S$ is 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&3/2\\3/2&3\end{array}\right).$$

Then ours expression  for $F$ is
$$F(p)=p^{\top}Qp=p^{\top}(S+A)p=p^{\top}Sp,\qquad (**)$$
because it is easy to compute $p^{\top}Ap=0$.

Also note that
$$F(x,y)=(x,y)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&3/2\\3/2&3\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)=x^2+3xy+3y^2.$$
Then the sign of $F$ will depend on the symmetric quadratic form $p^{\top}Sp$.

To decide the sign of this function, knowing that the level curve $x^2+3xy+3y^2=1$ is a tilted ellipse, one should try to calculate a new basis for the vectorspace $\Bbb R^2$. 
This change gives a pair of axes that one gets from the eigenvectors of the matrix $S$.

The eigenvectors are 
$$v_1=-\frac{2+\sqrt{13}}{3}e_1+e_2,$$ 
and 
$$v_2=\frac{-2+\sqrt{13}}{2}e_1+e_2.$$

With these, one can take the matrix 
$$B=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{2+\sqrt{13}}{3}&-\frac{2-\sqrt{13}}{3}\\
1&1
\end{array}\right),$$
and to get the interpretation of the quadratic form in $(**)$ with the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$, this will be through the formula $B^{\top}QB$ (this is dubbed orthogonal diagonalization for $Q$).

So the quadratic form for $S$ is
$$p^{\top}Sp=({BB^{-1}p})^{\top}SBB^{-1}p=(B^{-1}p)^{\top}(B^{\top}SB)B^{-1}p$$

Hence any can compute that the resulting expression is
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x,y)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&3/2\\3/2&3\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)
&=&
(s,t)B^{\top}SB
\left(\begin{array}{c}s\\t\end{array}\right)\\
&=&
(s,t)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{26-5\sqrt{13}}{9}&0\\
0&\frac{26+5\sqrt{13}}{9}\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}s\\t\end{array}\right)\\
&=&
\frac{26-5\sqrt{13}}{9}s^2+\frac{26+5\sqrt{13}}{9}t^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Since both $\frac{26-5\sqrt{13}}{9},\frac{26+5\sqrt{13}}{9}$ are positive, then
$F(x,y)>0$ as well as $x,y$ aren't zero simultaneously.

We have 
$\left(\begin{array}{c}s\\t\end{array}\right)=B^{-1}p$ 
to compute the new components of any vector $p=\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: to check some of the claims that I made you can use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B1%2C3%2F2%7D%2C%7B3%2F2%2C3%7D%7D

Comment: For (3) the function $F(x,y)=x+2y^2$ has a level curve the parabola $x+2y^2=0$ , with she, you have a partition of the plane into three zones... you will decide how is the sign of $F$ by choosing some points: in the concave part choose, let say $(−1,0)$ and for the right-most zone choose $(1,0)$... How is the sign of $F$ on them?

Comment: The sign of F changes  by the value of x.

Comment: that is a sample of $x+2y^2<0$ in concave part and $x+2y^2>0$ in the other